# MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, phpmyadmin

I've just started to learn MySQL and JDBC.

I created a table called testdb using phpmyadmin. Table just has 2 columns called first and last. When I am trying to connect the database from my java class, I get MySQLSyntaxError. However I could not figure it out.

Here is my class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb";

        //Accessing driver from the JAR file.
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        //Creating a variable for the connection "con"
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","password");

        //Here is the query
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from name");

        //Execute query
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

        while(result.next()) {
            System.out.println(result.getString(1) + " " + result.getString(2));
        }


    }

}
```

And here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'testdb.name' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
    at Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'testdb.name' doesn't exist
```

error is pretty much descriptive. There is not table with name "name" in `testdb` schema.

> I created a table called **testdb** using phpmyadmin.

If you have created table `testdb` then it should be `select * from testdb`. isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You've created a table named **testdb** therefore your query should be

```
select * from testdb
```

not `select * from name`

you should really check your stacktraces.